# SVG to PNG, colors lost

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, nvd3.js

I am trying to convert my `nvd3.js` charts into `canvas` drawings in my web app. There is a good `stackoverflow` thread about it: [How to convert/save d3.js graph to pdf/jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049538/how-to-convert-save-d3-js-graph-to-pdf-jpeg)

I decided to use `Simg` library and it is working good except that it generates me black and white images, the colors are lost. The code for the `Simg` library is small and can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krunkosaurus/simg/v1.1.0/src/simg.js

As I understand the main function that is actually doing the convertion is the following one:

```
toCanvas: function(cb){
  this.toSvgImage(function(img){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    cb(canvas);
  });
},
```

So, what should I modify there to avoid losing colors of my charts? They are drawn using `nvd3` and look like that:

[image]

The output of `Simg` library is the following image:

[image]

As you can see, the color and axes are lost. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried using `canvg()` but the output that I got is the following:

[image]

I just ran two lines of code:

```
let svg = d3.select("div#main svg").html();
canvg('canvas', svg);
```

I like that the axes are not lost but obviously it is unacceptable.

> Update

I tried using the code from the `duplicate` suggested link but it is not working for me. Here is the code that I am using:

```
let svg = d3.select("div#main svg").node();
console.log(svg);

var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var styleStr = '';
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sheets, function(sheet){
    try{ // we need a try-catch block for external stylesheets that could be there...
        styleStr += Array.prototype.reduce.call(sheet.cssRules, function(a, b){
            return a + b.cssText; // just concatenate all our cssRules' text
            }, "");
        }
    catch(e){console.log(e);}
});
// create our svg nodes that will hold all these rules
var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
var style = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style');
style.innerHTML = styleStr;
defs.appendChild(style);
// now append it in your svg node
svg.insertBefore(defs, svg.firstElementChild);

let xml = xmlserializer.serializeToString(svg);

            // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
//xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

canvg('canvas', xml);
```

It throws an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '38%' is not a valid selector.
>       at matchesSelector (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:72:16)
>       at svg.Element.g.addStylesFromStyleDefinition (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:838:32)
>       at svg.Element.g.svg.Element.ElementBase (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:864:10)
>       at svg.Element.g.svg.Element.RenderedElementBase (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:902:9)
>       at new svg.Element.g (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:2430:9)
>       at Object.svg.CreateElement (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:2832:9)
>       at svg.Element.svg.addChild (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:830:29)
>       at svg.Element.svg.svg.Element.ElementBase (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:889:40)
>       at svg.Element.svg.svg.Element.RenderedElementBase (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:902:9)
>       at new svg.Element.svg (http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js:1035:9)

If I avoid using `xmlserializer` and instead do the following: `canvg('canvas', d3.select(svg).html());`, then no errors are thrown, except some `404`s and nothing is drawn on the page, `canvas` element just stays empty. The only errors that I see in that case are:

[image]

> Update

I tried to use `Simg.js` to download the modified `svg` with the styles, but it is not working, nothing is just happening, no errors (I eliminated the errors in the previous update):

```
var simg = new Simg(svg);
simg.download();
```

Comment: Your issue is still the same as the dupe: you must include your CSS in the svg markup itself. As for the error you get, this means that one of your CSS files contains invalid rules, where a  `38%` value is parsed as a selector. Browsers will ignore it, but canvg code won't. Fix your CSS file and it should work. Anyhow, without a real [mcve] showing the actual svg produced, it's hard to help you further. You might try my old [SVG2Bitmap](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) script though I stopped the development of it in an incomplete state.

Comment: I just solved all the issues using your library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094256/convert-inline-svg-to-canvas-using-canvg-script    Awesome!

Comment: Is there a way of getting the actual converted image in code with your library? Function `SVG2Bitmap(svg, canvas);` just converts svg and draws it into `canvas`, but I need to get the image and append it in different places. Probably I could just access the canvas, but maybe you have some function already for it.